# too many arguments given a function

Tags: lisp

I'm having an error that i don't understand why...
"too many arguments given to ULTIMO"
The purpose of this function is to return the last element of a list

```
(defun ultimo (lst)
  (cond ((= 1 (length lst))
         (first lst)))
        (t
         (ultimo (rest lst))))
```

Comment: without proper formatting your attempts to program in Lisp will be hopeless. :-(

Answer (score 4):

There is a problem with the parentheses. The function should be defined in this way:

```
(defun ultimo (lst)
    (cond ((= 1 (length lst)) (first lst))
          (t (ultimo (rest lst)))))
```

Note that by using an editor that can format correctly lisp syntax this kind of errors happens very rarely.

However, your function does not manage correctly the empty list case (it enters an endless loop). A correct version could be:

```
(defun ultimo (lst)
  (cond ((null list) nil)
        ((null (rest list)) (first lst))
        (t (ultimo (rest lst))))
```

As a side note, consider that using the `length` function in a context like this is not recommended, since it is executed by visiting the entire list,